# Linux on Power SDK QEMU Debugging with GDB

Tags: linux, gdb, cross-compiling, qemu, powerpc

I'm checking out the [Linux on Power SDK](https://developer.ibm.com/linuxonpower/sdk/) and want to have a setup using QEMU (Setup 2 from the tutorial page).
So far I've got the SDK, [advance toolchain](https://developer.ibm.com/linuxonpower/advance-toolchain/) cross compiler and qemu-user-space-emulator all installed on Ubuntu 16.04. The whole process was quite painstaking since the [user guide](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/server/iplsdk/v1.10.0/docs/liaal_pdf.pdf) and all other infos often don't refer to the correct package locations and names or redirect to dead links.

I've got a "Hello world" project that I can run with the QEMU setting as described in the user guide but I cannot figure out how to get a debug build and step through the process running in QEMU using GDB. I have to add I'm not too familiar with Eclipse and using QEMU other than virtualizing a whole guest system.
Having command line debugging access is a first step but in the end I want it controllable from the IDE (setting breakpoints on lines, etc.).
Has anybody found any better documentation or knows if this is possible at all?

Comment: Just to clarify: you're running a binary compiled for POWER within quemu, and qemu is running on an x86 machine, is that right?

Comment: @JeremyKerr exactly. The binary is cross-compiled on an x86_64 machine for ppc64 using IBM's advance toolchain. They also provide a qemu user space emulator for ppc. The binary is run in that environment.